# Showing a sequence is in $\ell^1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be nonnegative sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ with $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$, $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$, and $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a convergent sequence. Furthermore, assume that $(1-a_n)p_{n+1}-p_n+r_n\leq e_n$ holds for all $n$. I want to show that $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$. Here is my attempt at a proof:

$\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |r_n| = \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} r_n \leq \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e_n+p_n+(a_n-1)p_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e_n +\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(p_n-p_{n+1}) +\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_np_n$.

Since $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, it is bounded above by some $M\in \mathbb{R}$. Using this we can write,

$\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e_n +p_1-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n +\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_np_n\leq \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e_n +p_1-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n +M\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n<\infty$.

The sum $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e_n$ is finite as $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is nonnegative in $\ell^1$ and similarly for the sum $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$. Thus $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$.

Is this sufficient?

Comment: All sequences considered are nonnegative, as stated in the first line.

Comment: To show $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \left( e_n + p_n +(a_n-1)p_{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} e_n + \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (p_n-p_{n+1}) + \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n p_n$, you need to know the series  all converge.  They do, but worth pointing out.

Comment: Okay that was what I was mostly wondering about, so we know that the first and last converge because they are in $\ell^1$ and the middle sum is telescoping with a convergent summand. is that sufficient?

Comment: Good enough for me

Comment: I also think this is OK